# Free Scrum tool that integrates with GitHub

Tags: gratis, project-management, github

I'm looking for a free (as in free beer) Scrum tool that integrates with private GitHub projects. It should also be hosted, there are a few open source (free software) projects out there but I don't want to spend too much time setting up and maintaining such tools.

[Jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/buy/) has a free plan but only for public projects. Others like [Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/) are only free for 30 days, but that's not enough time to get a good idea. I'd be ok with it if it were free for one year.

I've used [ScrumDo](https://scrumdo.com/) in the past but 20$/month is not an option for a bootstrapping startup project.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Taiga.io](https://taiga.io/) can be a good candidate. It's not as smooth to set up as ScrumDo but it's free as in free software and free as in free software until July 2015, afterwards 3$/month for a small project.

*Update based on @chmac's comment.*

Comment: Looks interesting, but it's only free for private projects until July 2015, which is more than 30 days, less than a year.

Comment: I guess things might have been different in 2015, but [self-hosting Taiga is free](https://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/). And it looks nice, but their GitHub integration [is quite limited](https://tree.taiga.io/support/integrations/github-integration/).

Answer (score 0):

[Scrumfast.com](https://www.scrumfast.com) is a good new resource in case folks are coming here looking for answers to this old question.  $4 a month.

Comment: Can you describe why such program complies with the question?